# List of specific database tables that a user has access

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in MySQL management, so I need help in writing query for listing specific database tables that a user has access.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange wish...

Normally users should not be interested in tables. Tables are a technical aspect of the data model, something that should not be visible to the user. The user is interested in storing and retrieving data. But he usually is and should not be aware of how that data is stored.

Anyways: there is no such function AFAIK. you will have to create some hack yourself. You can query the list of tables inside a database. Then you'd have to iterate over that list and test for access rights one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mysql information_schema tables.

> 19.14 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_PRIVILEGES Table
>
> The TABLE_PRIVILEGES table provides information about table
>   privileges. This information comes from the mysql.tables_priv grant
>   table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-privileges-table.html

and

> 6.2.2 Privilege System Grant Tables
>
> Normally, you manipulate the contents of the grant tables in the mysql
>   database indirectly by using statements such as GRANT and REVOKE to
>   set up accounts and control the privileges available to each one. See
>   Section 13.7.1, “Account Management Statements”. The discussion here
>   describes the underlying structure of the grant tables and how the
>   server uses their contents when interacting with clients.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant-table-structure.html